# Show levels of interactions between movie characters with Neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, graph-databases

I am working on a little project to learn more about graph analytics. I have dialogs from the TV show Archer to which I added a *speaker* fields and a *speaking to*field. To show the level of interaction, I am using a basic wordcount.

My data looks like this:

```
TEXT           Speaker    Speaking_to     Wordcount
Bla bla        Archer     Lana            2
Bla            Archer     Lana, Cyril     1
Bla bla bla    Lana       Archer, Cyril   3
```

I would use the wordcount sums between every combination of *speaker* to *speaking_to* to show the strength of the characters interaction between each other.

How would you proceed in Neo4j?
How to you model the cases where I have multiple *speaking_to* characters? I want all my nodes to be individual characters and not groups.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Model:**

- two types of nodes - the person and the text
- two types of relationships - who speaks and to whom appeals

[image]

```
MERGE (A:Person {name:'Archer'}) 
MERGE (L:Person {name:'Lana'}) 
MERGE (C:Person {name:'Cyril'})

MERGE (T1:Text {name: 'Bla bla', wc: 2}) 
MERGE (T2:Text {name: 'Bla', wc: 1}) 
MERGE (T3:Text {name: 'Bla bla bla', wc: 3})

MERGE (A)-[:Speaking]->(T1) 
  MERGE (T1)-[:Speaking_to]->(L)
MERGE (A)-[:Speaking]->(T2)
  MERGE (T2)-[:Speaking_to]->(C)
  MERGE (T2)-[:Speaking_to]->(C)
MERGE (L)-[:Speaking]->(T3)
  MERGE (T3)-[:Speaking_to]->(A)
  MERGE (T3)-[:Speaking_to]->(C)
```

Strength of directional interaction:

```
MATCH (A:Person)-[:Speaking]->(S:Text)-[:Speaking_to]->(P:Person)
  RETURN A.name, P.name, sum(S.wc) as wordcount 
  ORDER BY wordcount DESC
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to show the strength of directional interaction using a graph rather than a table?

Comment: If you ask about `neo4j browser` - no, impossible. Try third-party libraries, a lot of them. https://github.com/anvaka/graph-drawing-libraries